# What is the difference between being inside or outside of fate from a mechanical point of view?

Tags: exalted

"Outside of Fate" is something that is often mentioned in Exalted.

However, while I can find fluff about it, I couldn't find much mechanical information. Currently, I only found the following:

- Resistance to Charms with the Fate keyword
- Immune to Astrology
- Difficult to track

Is that it? Or are there other ***mechanical*** differences?

Comment: I've voted to put this on hold as Too Broad. This question does not articulate a clear, specific problem for answerers to solve, and in its current form would be best addressed by reading the rulebooks. Scoping this question more clearly to an in-play circumstance you have encountered will help make it more answerable.

Comment: @Grubermensch I don't see any problem here. There are plenty of questions on this SE that could be solved by reading the rulebooks. In that case, the question is pretty straightforward, and has an answer in the rulebooks, but spread a bit all over the place. It is definitely possible to summarize all those little pieces into one concise and definitive answer, especially since OP has specifically asked about mechanical information.

Comment: A lot of it is in the Manual of Exalted Powers: The Sidereals, but yeah, random other things scattered in the Yu-Shan book, Rolls of Glorous Powers, etc.

Comment: [This recent meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/is-our-interpretation-of-too-broad-too-narrow) discusses why we consider "explain the rules to me" questions as Too Broad.

Comment: To improve this question, please edit it to tell us what information you've found, and specifically what you're confused by in what you've found.

Comment: @Grubermensch That meta discussion seems to be specifically about "explain this basic rule section from the core book". I don't think it applies to any question whose answers use elements from the rulebooks - since that is the case for 80% of the questions here. This question needs some good knowledge about the system to know where to find the info and to explain it. It has one answer, which would most include 6-10 bullet points. As such, I really don't think it fits the "too broad" category.

Comment: Edited it, just in case it helps.

Answer (score 2):

That's about all that's explicitly stated but you can draw some mechanical implications from the fluff.

Things without a Fate (Fair Folk, Undead, Autochthonians, some Yozi and Infernals, Etc.) seriously mess with the Loom when they interact with Creation. They cannot be seen with divination or other attempts to predict the future and any prophesy goes of the rails as soon as something Fateless gets involved. Butterfly effect style.